# Why doesn't a generic of Integer assigned a value of String issue an error when printed?

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

The question can also be viewed as: Why does a generic of String assigned a value of Integer issue a run time error when it's printed? But the answer to that question seems obvious, the title question does not to me. I do not understand why there is an error for one and not the other. The problem applies to this example. Let's say you have a parameterized Box class:

```
class Box <T> {
    T value;

    void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and you have three instances of this class, one has no type argument and the other two have either String or Integer. The Box of String and Integer are instantiated to the raw object:

```
    Box rawBox = new Box();
    Box <Integer> intBox = rawBox;
    Box <String> stringBox = rawBox;
```

When we pass setValue() values via the raw reference and print getValue() via respective parameterized references the question I am having arises:

```
    Integer integerVal = 4;
    rawBox.setValue(integerVal);
    System.out.println(intBox.getValue());
    // System.out.println(stringBox.getValue()); // ClassCastException a Integer cannot be assigned to a String

    rawBox.setValue("hi");
    System.out.println(intBox.getValue()); // Why is there no ClassCastException for assigning a String to Integer?
    System.out.println(stringBox.getValue());
```

The ClassCastException error is only issued when the getValue() is printed, not when setValue() is invoked. So why is it that a parameterized object with a type argument of Integer instantiated to a rawtype can assign it's generic a value of String via the raw reference and have no run time error when the getValue() is printed but if the same parameterized type has a type argument of String and it's generic is assigned a value of Integer via raw type it will throw a ClassCastException when it's getValue() is printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably understand that `Box.value` is an `Object` at runtime and that therefore `Box.getValue` must return `Object`.

There are overloads of `PrintStream.println` for all the primitive types, for `Object`, and for `String`. This is presumably to avoid an extra call to `Object.toString` when the value being printed is known to be a `String`.

So imagine what the generated bytecode will look like for the two calls to `println`:

```
Integer integerVal = 4;
rawBox.setValue(integerVal);
System.out.println(intBox.getValue());
```

In this case, `intBox.getValue()` returns `Object`, and so we're going to call the version of `println` that accepts `Object`. The compiler knows that the return value is supposed to be `Integer`, but that doesn't matter, because there's no overload of `println` that accepts `Integer`.

```
System.out.println(stringBox.getValue());
```

Here, while `stringBox.getValue()` returns `Object`, the compiler knows that it should be a `String` and wants to call the version of `println` that accepts a `String`. That requires downcasting the return value to `String`, which fails because it's actually an `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up but your explanation raises another question, and it's possibly a dumb one. I understand that getValue() will be an Object no matter how it's called but isn't intBox.getValue() an Object of type Integer and stringBox.getValue() an Object of type String? Whereas Box.getValue() is an Object of type Object and rawBox.getValue() is an Object of type Object? I'm a little thrown off by this. Your answer would make complete sense to me if stringBox.getValue() is of type String because as you said the compiler knows it should be a String

Comment: The Java compiler knows what type `T` is, but the generic type information is unavailable to the JVM due to erasure. There's only one `Box.getValue` method in the JVM, and it returns `Object`. Imagine that you were writing this in 2003, and there were no generics, and all you had was `Box` with its member `value`. You define `stringBox` and you know that `stringBox.value` is really a String, and you want to pass it to the `String` version of `println`. If you just do `println(stringBox.value)` you'll get the wrong one, so you have to do `println((String)stringBox.value))`.

Comment: Now it's pretty obvious that if, somewhere else in your code, you set `stringBox.value` to `4`, the call to `println` will fail with `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Okay so why does it work for `intBox`? Again, imagine you're writing this without generics. You know that `intBox.value` is an Integer and you want to pass it to `println`. However, in this case there is no `println(Integer)`. The one you need to use takes an `Object`. And since `intBox.value` already *is* an `Object`, there is no need to add a cast. If you later set `intBox.value` to `"hello"` then you'll just be passing `"hello"` to `println`. It will work because there's no attempt to cast it to `Integer`.

Comment: 4 Months later and I'm just now reading about type erasure. The article I'm reading is type erasure specific and therefore does not cover the effects of type erasure in a print stream. I thought I'd let you know your answer has continued to help me to this day and point me in a direction of other things to learn. Thanks for the solid answer. Keep at it please!